# Which theory do we use when dealing with the center of a star?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, stellar-physics

The center of a black hole is known as being one of the locations in spacetime that needs an unification theory between quantum physics and general relativity, because of having a large mass in a small space. I was wondering if that problem would arise as well in the center of a common star (say the Sun for example), or if we had a theoretical framework apt to deal with such situations? (and if yes, which one?)

Another way to put up the question would be: which equation precisely goes to infinity in the case of the center of a black hole, and does it also go to infinity in the case of a common star?

Comment: In a star below the [Schwarzschild radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) there is no singularity. Reading the link is most of your question answered.

Comment: The spherically symmetric relativity solutions with matter are well-behaved until one reaches gravitational collapse. Solving the hydrostatic equilibrium for various kinds of matter runs into limiting points when the mass reaches the Chandrasekar limit (or similar limits where degeneracy pressure cannot support the star) but then the effect is an implosion to a denser form of matter (or a black hole).